# When are there buses from Skopje to Pristina on 5-6 January?

Tags: planning, buses, macedonia, kosovo

I'm going from Skopje to Pristina by bus, and have to arrive in Pristina on 6 January no later than 04:50 to catch a connecting bus to Sweden.

I now want to know what bus I should take from Skopje. However, the timetable on the [official website of Skopje's bus station](http://sas.com.mk/VozenRed.aspx) is **not** reliable (in my own experience) and when calling them and asking (in Macedonian) whether they spoke English or German the lady brusquely said "ne!" and hung up.

So: does anyone know when the last bus leaves from Skopje for Pristina arriving in Pristina no later than 04:50 on 6 January?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bus station staff said there would be a bus at 19:10 and one at 21:30, but the 21:30 one never showed up, and at 22:00, I told them to contact the bus company, who said that bus had been spontaneously cancelled for that day.

Had to take a taxi, whereby I was conned (lesson for next time - hopefully never as I don't normally take taxis: always write on a piece of paper the agreed price). First the driver wanted 60 euros (which was recommended to me by a security guard at Skopje's bus station), but then he said (in Macedonian) "no no, HUNDRED sixty", and then he wanted 15 euros for the Kosovo insurance, which he never mentioned at first.

So, I had to pay 175 euros instead of just 5 euros for the bus (which I at least got back) to get to Pristina on time

Comment: Added lesson, never plan to take the last bus if you can use the one but last with not much more time loss.

Answer (score 2):

There are several bus companies running in the Balkans countries with either downgraded websites or without websites. The correct information regarding last bus from Skopje would always be available from the bus stop in Skopje Macedonia.

Further to your question when the last bus leaves form Skopje to Pristine on Jan 5 to 6.   Although there are many buses running in between those stops I  have personally bought bus tickets from [Balkan Viator](https://www.balkanviator.com/en/bus-timetables/skopje-mkd/pristina/05.01.2017) and found at least this website up to date.

At least from this website, the last bus leaving Skopje at 20:50 and arriving Pristina at 22:50 on Jan 5.